# Are there different ways to set value of a struct field?

Tags: go

I came across a code on [github.com/go-github](https://github.com/google/go-github/blob/ab35a4779b48b6089e8d3a80cc99c544695853eb/github/github.go#L260) repository and there they used a different way to set struct field. I could not understand that syntax. The sample code is given below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)
type Client struct{
    X int

    common service // To reuse same struct instead of creating new for each service

    Activity *ActivityService
    Reply *ReplyService
}

type ActivityService service
type ReplyService service
type service struct{
    client *Client
}


func NewClient() *Client {
    c := &Client{X:5}
    c.common.client = c


    c.Activity = (*ActivityService)(&c.common)
    c.Reply = &ReplyService{client: c}

    return c
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

In this code `Activity` field is set with `(*ActivityService)(&c.common)` which returns no error in playground. I guess this is valid syntax. Could you explain me this syntax ?

Syntax I am aware of is this `&ReplyService{client:c}`

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/i8ACagwMQMH)

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being a struct field - a variable `foo := (*ActivityService)(&c.common)` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

> c.Activity = (*ActivityService)(&c.common)

This is Type conversions (https://tour.golang.org/basics/13)
Such as `ActivityService` type is based on `service` type and `c.common` is `service` then it works fine